# Android: ScrollView containing two nested ConstraintLayouts, cant fill screen horizontally

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am having an issue with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/block"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="#419E9E9E"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/block"></LinearLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/holder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/holderText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="Hello World"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/holder" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="Button"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Vertically, the layout does what I want: it puts the last layout and fills the screen.
However, when the device is flipped horizontally, the bottom portion (the nested constraintlayout) disappears due to the constraint on itself of                 `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

"How do I fill the screen with a second layout while still having it scroll horizontally ?"

I have attached pics and a demo repository to isolate the problem.

**Link:** https://github.com/taesookim0412/StackOverflow_Question_Android_NestedConstraintLayouts_ScrollView

[image: vertical]

[image: hznt'l]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Instead of minHeight, you can use

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_min="100dp"
```